# Remove some images from a graphics app to make more space but keep the app. Possible?

Tags: data-transfer, disk-space

In the olden days when you had a lot of files on a computer you just saved them on a hard drive and kept using the software without an issue. I want to do something similar with an ipad.
I use graphics apps which have created a lot of images. I don't need access to them all all the time, so I would like to move them onto my computer to make space on the ipad.

I still want to use the app, so offloading it isn't an option.

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks

PS - I want to be able to reopen the files with the ipad app in the future so just exporting them and saving them as finished images won't work.

Comment: Are you familiar with OneDrive and iCloud storage using the files app? They all offload the originals to the cloud so you can have many hundreds of gigabytes of files in the cloud and only use space if you download or pin a file on iOS. Adobe offers this service with creative cloud as well so it might just be about learning how your apps can use other file storage idioms. Not sure if this is the answer so let’s clarify what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I have icloud backing up, I'm not sure how to use it as the only place where files are saved. Also, I have the app set to use icloud, but when I go to files I can't see any of its files in icloud drive. But you've given hope it's possible, I'll start searching for info on how to do it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple (and others) offer cloud sync between iOS and computers. I would start there until you know how to use your specific graphic app behaves. You can also transfer files off iPad and iPhone using Finder in macOS without using the files app.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/files/id1232058109
- https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/transfer-files-iphone-computer-iphf2d851b9/ios
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206481

The nice thing with files is you can augment it with third party storage options and move files between apps rather than store items in each app sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, bmike.I have investigated but got no further.The app I am using doesn’t show up in Files.When I connect via a Mac it doesn’t allow access to the files for this app via the Files tab and anyway that seems to be a way of copying from the iPad and not back to it. iCloud is on for the app,but the storage page still tells me it’s using a lot of space.I looked through the links you kindly left but I can’t find a solution.It seems weird that files from only a few apps are showing up in Files. Without seeing my files I don’t see how to go forward.Thx for any suggestions anyone

Comment: Bingo @AskingQuestions if your apps sandbox their files, you are dependent upon them to help. You manage space. Or you’ll delete those apps and choose others you can manage effectively when their size out weights their utility to you.